# variants declaration in CMakelist #cmake #Cmakelist

Tags: cmake

```
file(GLOB FILE_LIST "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp")
```

Can anyone explain, in which case is GLOB used as the argument of file() in CMakelist.txt?

Comment: I'm unsure what you are asking, but the documentation for `file(GLOB ...)` is [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob).

Comment: thank you, i understand right now.